# Pointwise limit of the sequence of functions $h_n(x)=1,\, \forall x\ge 1/n$ and $h_n(x)=nx,\,\forall x\in[0,1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Pointwise limit of the sequence of functions

$$h_n(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x\ge \frac1n\\nx,&\text{if }x\in[0,\frac1n)\end{cases}$$

The trouble with this question is that I think that $h(0)$ is not defined but Im not completely sure. We can see that for any $n\in\Bbb N$ we have that $h_n(0)=0$. But the sequence $h_n(x)=1$ is approaching to zero as well but only reach zero in the limit cause $\lim 1/n=0$.

Are my assumptions correct? It is $h(0)$ undefined?

Comment: You have that $h_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ since $0\in[0,\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$. So $h(0)=0$. Your point about $h_n(x)=1$ is a different point, that just shows that $h(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that by $h$ you mean the pointwise limit of $(h_n)$: no, $h(0)$ is defined. In fact, $h(0) :=\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(0) = 0$.

What is confusing you is that $h$ is not continuous. We have for $x > 0$, there exists $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $x > 1/k$, so $h_n(x) = 1$ for all $n \ge k$, thus $h_n(x) \to 1$. This shows that:

$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0, x = 0 \\ 1, x > 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand... I get confused due the interval $x\ge 1/n$ and it convergence. But I realized that what define the value of a limit is not the interval, just the points that are converging prior to "reach" the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You have $h_1(0)=0$, $h_2(0)=0$, $h_3(0)=0$, $h_4(0)= 0$, etc.  So the sequence $h_1(0), h_2(0), h_3(0), h_4(0), h_5(0),\ldots$ is just the sequence $0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$ in which every term is $0$.  That sequence does have a limit and the limit is $0$.  In other words $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(0) = 0$.  The limit does exist and is $0$.

If $x>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)=1$.  So this is an example of a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a discontinuous function.